# Probability random binary number lies in an interval

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, binary

Suppose we have a sequence $\{d_n\}$ where all the $d_n$ are either 1 or 0, with equal probability. Let $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n2^{-n}$. I need to show that $\mathbb{P}(x \in [a,b])=b-a$.

I started by assuming the interval is of the form $[p/2^n,q/2^n]$ with the hope that I can later get arbitrary $a,b$ by using suitable set operations. I then noted that $\mathbb{P}(x \in [p/2^n,q/2^n])=1-\mathbb{P}(x \in [0,p/2^n])-\mathbb{P}(x \in [q/2^n,1])$.

In order to get a feel for the problem, I tried working out $\mathbb{P}(x \in [0,p/2^n])$ for $p/2^n=0.11010011_2$. In this case, an arbitrary binary number lying in the interval $[0,p/2^n]$ can begin in one of 5 different ways:

$0.0_2,0.10_2,0.1100_2,0.1101000_2,0.11010010_2$

I then noted that these numbers have 1,2,4,7 and 8 digits after the decimal respectively, which is the same position that 1s appear in  $p/2^n$. This establishes the required result, but I am unsure how to generalise this to arbitrary $p$. I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

This is for a measure theory class.

Comment: Something needs tweaking above. If the sum defining $x$ starts at $n=0$ then the range of $x$ is $[0,2]$and the probability needs to be something like $P[x \in [a,b]] = {1 \over 2} (\min(b,2),\max(a,0))$. Or start the sum at $n=1$.

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

I am assuming that the number corresponding to a given $d$ is $x(d) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n { 1\over 2^n}$, that is, the sum starts at $n=1$.

I am also assuming that the $d_n$ are fair and independent. It follows from this that
$P[(d_1,...,d_n) \in A] = P[(d_{i_1},...,d_{i_n}) \in A]$ for any $P$ measurable set $A$ and for any set of distinct indices $i_1,...,i_n$. It follows
from this that if we let $\theta_k(d) = (d_k,d_{k+1},...)$, then
$P[d \in A] = P[\theta_k(d) \in A]$. (By 'it follows' I mean that it can be shown with a little work :-).)

It is straightforward to see that $x(d) \in [0,1]$ for all $d$, and so
$P[x(d) \in [0,1]] = 1$.

It is also straightforward to see that $x(d) = 1$ **iff** $d_n=1$ for all $n$ and
so $P[x(d) = 1] = 0$.

Hence $P[x(d) \in [0,1)] = 1$.

Pick some $n$ and let $k \in \{0,...,2^n \}$

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
P[x(d) \in [{k \over 2^n}, {k+1 \over 2^n}) ] &=& P[2^n x(d) \in [k,k+1) ] \\
&=& P[ 2^{n-1} d_1+\cdots + d_n + \sum_{k > n} d_k {2^n \over 2^k} \in [k,k+1) ] \\
&=& P[2^{n-1} d_1+\cdots + d_n =k \text{ and } \sum_{k > n} d_k {2^n \over 2^k} \in [0,1) ] \\
&& \ \  +P[2^{n-1} d_1+\cdots + d_n =k-1 \text{ and } \sum_{k > n} d_k {2^n \over 2^k} =1 ] \\
&=& P[2^{n-1} d_1+\cdots + d_n =k] \\
&=& {1 \over 2^n}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $P[x(d) \in [0,{k \over 2^n})] = {k \over 2^n}$, and hence
$P[x(d) \in [0, t)] = t$, for $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Just fixed small bug in proof (added third last line in the set of equations above).